# ERROR: detaching thread with interp frames (count=4)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have a java project. This is loading a library .so and in a thread is calling a jni method from this .so.
The problem is every time the method finish ,the app crash too and the message I see is "ERROR: detaching thread with interp frames (count=4)" . What i have to do to clean exit from that native method?

Comment: You need to show some code. `AttachCurrentThread` doesn't really do anything if the current thread already was attached to the VM, but `DetachCurrentThread` always tries to detach the calling thread. So it sounds like you forgot to check whether the thread already was attached, which determines whether or not you should call `DetachCurrentThread`.

Comment: You should show the code for the native function you're calling.

Comment: i think java thread finish ,but the native code is not finished yet? i really do not knwo what's happening . I dnt undstand what it exactly complain with that error

Comment: Someone is trying to detach the thread, but there is some Java-language code that hasn't finished executing.  Any Java code must return to the top  of the stack before the thread can be detached.  If you want to know where the thread is being detached from, look at the native stack trace in logcat.